# How to access cefSharp inside react

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, cefsharp

I'm trying to load react url inside C# .net application.I want to access cefSharp object inside our React  application.
like this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof CefSharp !== "undefined") {
      (async function() {
        await CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("cefCustomObject");

        cefCustomObject.showDevTools();
        cefCustomObject.writetodebug("test","testestestest");
        cefCustomObject.opencmd();
      })();
    }
  }, []);
```

I have seen using above code in vue.I want to do same with react.
EDIT: 
Used window object.Now it throws error for window.cefCustomObject.showDevTools()

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window.CefSharp !== "undefined") {
      (async function() {
        await window.CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("cefCustomObject");

        window.cefCustomObject.showDevTools();
        window.cefCustomObject.writetodebug("test","testestestest");
        window.cefCustomObject.opencmd();
      })();
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: Try accessing the object/methods via the `window` object, e.g. `window.CefSharp.BindObjectAsync`

Comment: when I used window.CefSharp works fine in browser but inside window.Forms() it throws errors for window.cefCustomObject.showDevTools();

Comment: @amaitland is there any webpack configuration for this issue

Comment: What errors? Edit your question to provide more detail please. Provide details of what is working, what's not working, the errors you are seeing. You can use `DevTools` for debugging javascript see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging

Comment: Must saying there are errors doesn't help,  you need to detail what the errors actually are.